WPF tooltip issue
I have created a custom tool tip style like this using XAML (Resource dictionary)
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#404040" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" />
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Grid>
                    <Path
                        Width="12"
                        Height="8"
                        Margin="6,2,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Data="M9.6 4.53333C9.8 4.26667 10.2 4.26667 10.4 4.53333L16 12H4L9.6 4.53333Z"
                        Fill="#404040"
                        Stretch="Fill" />

                    <Border
                        Margin="0,10,0,0"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        CornerRadius="3">
                        <TextBlock
                            Padding="8"
                            FontSize="12"
                            FontWeight="Normal"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

When the application is fully maximized and when i hover on the last button which is exactly at the right end side of the screen the tool tip is not exactly coming right below the button, what i need to fix here?
Issue:
Yellow arrow is where i hover the mouse and the little triangle of the tooltip style is not coming right below the last button in this list of buttons.

For other button:


Your explanations and code are not enough to reproduce the problem.
I have copied your code, but for me the output is as intended.

Path .... HorizontalAlignment="Right". Your app needs to be "aware" of which side to orient to; based on available space. Bind HorizontalAlignment; or use the dreaded "code behind". (And you want to tinker with the Path's margin). And you can logically "stack" buttons to gain screen space if that makes sense.

@EldHasp, When i change the application window state to maximized state, this is issue is happening. Place any control right at the end of the window and after maximizing the screen you can see this issue.

I wanted to show you screenshots that show that when I repeat your code, everything is displayed as intended. Unfortunately, my answer was deleted, because there is a competition on the resource "who will delete more answers and questions". One of the problems of stackoverflow is that very often, instead of helping beginners, beginners are told that they are asking the question incorrectly. This resource treats beginners very badly.

I have restored my answer. I don't know how long it will last until the next deletion.
Here are links to screenshots
https://i.sstatic.net/IxUN7g5W.png
https://i.sstatic.net/xW9LlKiI.png

I understood your problem.
Now explain how you see its solution?
If the ToolTip window does not fit in the monitor range, then should the ToolTip be cut off, or should the "little triangle" be moved to the actual element?

@EldHasp, yes i want to move that "little triangle" below the actual element instead of being in out of position.

Unfortunately, my answer with the demonstration had to be deleted - there is a very negative community here that does not like detailed explanations, clarification of circumstances. In my answer, I had two screenshots, on one of which the ToolTip is shown on the corner element. But the ToolTip is positioned correctly in relation to the element, although it had to go beyond the window boundaries to do so.
Links to screenshots from my answer:
https://i.sstatic.net/IxUN7g5W.png  https://i.sstatic.net/xW9LlKiI.png

@EldHasp, can you please maximize the screen of the app and check? It may not fit ("little triangle")


can you please maximize the screen of the app and check? It may not fit ("little triangle")

Now I understand your problem.
Unfortunately I didn't find a simple way to solve your problem.
In my example I create an Attached Property to change the behavior of the Path - its positioning in the center of the PlacementTarget.
    public static class ToolTipHelper
    {
        public static FrameworkElement GetPlacementTarget(FrameworkElement elmt)
        {
            return (FrameworkElement)elmt.GetValue(PlacementTargetProperty);
        }

        public static void SetPlacementTarget(FrameworkElement elmnt, FrameworkElement value)
        {
            elmnt.SetValue(PlacementTargetProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PlacementTarget.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PlacementTargetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PlacementTarget",
                                                typeof(FrameworkElement),
                                                typeof(ToolTipHelper),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(null)
                                                {
                                                    PropertyChangedCallback = OnPlacementTargetChanged
                                                });

        private static void OnPlacementTargetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement elmt = (FrameworkElement)d;
            elmt.Loaded -= OnPlacementTargetChanged;
            elmt.Loaded += OnPlacementTargetChanged;
        }

        private static async void OnPlacementTargetChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1);
            FrameworkElement elmt = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            FrameworkElement target = GetPlacementTarget(elmt);
            if (elmt.RenderTransform is not TranslateTransform transform)
            {
                elmt.RenderTransform = transform = new TranslateTransform();
            }
            else if (transform.IsFrozen)
            {
                elmt.RenderTransform = transform = transform.Clone();
            }

            Point medium = new Point(elmt.ActualWidth / 2, 0);
            Point translate = elmt.TranslatePoint(medium, target);
            transform.X = target.ActualWidth / 2 - translate.X;
            Debug.WriteLine(transform.X);
        }
    }

Example of use:
<Window x:Class="Core2024.SO.Gururaj.question79009637.ToolTipWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2024.SO.Gururaj.question79009637"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ToolTipWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#404040" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  Data="M 0,8 L5,1 Q 6,0 7,1 L 12,8 Z"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  local:ToolTipHelper.PlacementTarget="{TemplateBinding PlacementTarget}">
                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="6" Y="1.5"/>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                            </Path>

                            <Border Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    CornerRadius="3">
                                <TextBlock Padding="8"
                                           FontSize="12"
                                           FontWeight="Normal"
                                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                           Text="TemplateBinding Content"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <UniformGrid Rows="1">
        <Button Content="1" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip/>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="2" Width="30" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip/>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>


